# Ubuntu + apache2 + ssl - AH00072 address alredy in use

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl

I'm new to server stuff. On Azure I run VirtualMachnine based on Ubuntu 14. I install apache2 and everything workd fine.

Now I need to add SSL certificate. So at default-ssl.conf I write:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mydomainname.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomainname.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mydomainname.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mydomainname.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

on laravel.conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomainname.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

but now when I try to start apache2 server I get: (98) Address alredy in use: make_sock: Colun now bind the address [::]:443

Ports used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S339r.png

**UPDATE:**

Now I have in portf.conf :

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

and I get error:

```
[Tue May 10 13:52:22.215535 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4063] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue May 10 13:52:23.304933 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4217] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_gnutls/0.5.10 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 10 13:52:23.304992 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4217] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

What is a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet for `Listen 443` being duplicated on your config files.

Comment: yes that was tru but now I get: [Tue May 10 13:40:13.695381 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3712] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue May 10 13:41:44.575548 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3712] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue May 10 13:41:45.611104 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3791] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_gnutls/0.5.10 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 10 13:41:45.611144 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3791] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
 WHY ????? please help

Comment: Post all of the output as an edit to the OP, not as a comment please

Comment: I update my question please help ... I post also ports.conf file...